# Extracting text based on a regex pattern with cheerio nodejs

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am trying to build a scraper with node.js which will allow me to extract news headlines from a large number of domains (they are all different so I have to be as general as possible in my approach). At the moment I have a working implementation in python which utilises Beautiful soup and regex allowing me to define a set of keywords and return headlines containing those keywords. Below is a relevant snippet of python code:

```
for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(keywords)))
```

To illustrate the expected output, lets assume there is a domain with news articles (Bellow is a html snippet containing a headline):

```
<a class="gs-c-promo-heading gs-o-faux-block-link__overlay-link gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__anchor" href="/news/uk-52773032"><h3 class="gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text">Time to end Clap for Carers, says founder</h3></a>
```

The expected output given a keyword *Time* would be a string with a headline *Time to end Clap for Carers*

My question is: is it possible to do a similar thing with cheerio? What would be the best approach to achieve the same results in nodejs?

EDIT: This works for me now. On top of matching headlines I also wanted to extract post urls

```
function match_headlines($) {

      const keywords = ['lockdown', 'quarantine'];

      new RegExp('\\b[A-Z].*?' + "(" + test_keywords.join('|') + ")" + 
                 '.*\\b', "g");

      let matches = $('a').map((i, a) => {

          let links = $(a).attr('href');
          let match = $(a).text().match(regexPattern);

          if (match !== null) {

             let posts = {

                 headline: match['input'],
                 post_url: links
             }

             return posts

          }

     })

     return matches.filter((x) => x !== null)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
let re = new RegExp('\\b' + keywords.join('|') + '\\b')
let texts = $('a h3').map((i, a) => $(a).text())
let titles = texts.filter(text => text.match(re))
```

Comment: Thanks! based on your suggestion this worked for me:

let regex_pattern = new RegExp('\\b[A-Z].*' + test_keywords.join('|') + '.*\\b/gm');
let headlines = $('a h3').map((i, a) =. {
                        $(a).text().match(regex_pattern)})

What happens though, is that headlines return a cheerio objects that for some reason I can't access. The reason for accessing those is that I also need to get urls to posts that get matched with the keywords

Comment: actually I think I figured it out - I will update the question